# csharp using sql query with special characters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, special-characters

I have a scenario in my csharp code where I am trying to get records with special characters / and % using sql query.

I tried executing query in sql query analyzer and it worked fine after adding square brackets.

```
Select * from tblDetails where name like '%[\]%' or name like '%[%]%'
```

But it fails when I use it in csharp

```
string sqlQuery = "Select * from tblDetails where name like '%[/]%' or name like '%[%]%' ";
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, strConnection))
```

Comment: fails how?   Do you get an error?   What is the error message?   Try using profiler to see what SQL command is being sent by your C# program.

Comment: Your code should work. What is the error you get?

Comment: I can't even run this sql query in the SQL Management studio. Are you sure you are not missing single quotes here "or name like %[%]%"?

Comment: I added the missing single quotes.

Comment: I am Sorry I am trying for a reverse slash '%[\]%'

Comment: are you trying for '%[\\]%'?  If so, you have to type `\\\`

Comment: If you are trying for ``\`` make sure you correct both your code examples, because right now, it's confusing, since you have ``\``  in the first, and `/` in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=xyz;server=abc";
    string sqlQuery = "Select * from myTable where name like '%[\\]%' or name like '%[%]%'";
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
    {
        var result = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string sqlQuery = @"Select * from tblDetails where name like '%[\]%' or name like '%[%]%' ";
```

@-operator ignores special characters in a string

EDIT: Well now this solution will work just fine

Comment: @ ignores *control characters*, not special characters, unfortunately this won't work.

Comment: Because @ won't ignore things like / or %, but it does copy literal into a string things like \n or \t. Adding the @ sign to the string above doesn't do anything because there are no control characters in it.